# No Miner can connect to RPC Server

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, gpu, windows

I'm new to this BitCoin, as in read about it yesterday started with it today. This technology has intrigued me to the level I cannot explain, its truly genius!

Back to my problem, I have a **NVIDIA NVS3100** with approx **48 GFlops speed**. I am using it to mine. I have taken part in different pools, but the problem is that miner is not connecting to the RPC server.
This is the error:

```
Could not retrieve work from RPC Server
CURL Return Value = 1
```

I'm using `rpcminer-cuda` made by **puddinpop** on **Windows 8**.

Would I have to make rules in firewall? or something like that?

Comment: can you post the command you are using to launch the application?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are having the same problem, please note that rpcminers are not supported by many BitCoin Miners, this was my problem.

I started to use GUIMiner and it accepted my first block just yesterday. No more blocks besides those yet, but well I'm just starting.

Regards

Thanks for all the help!